# Need to understand what is the use of [::-1] in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, slice

I tried to remove the part I got the result but only in reverse order. So my question here is that why are we using that part to splice the array.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("E:/tmp/pis.jpg")
template = cv2.imread("E:/tmp/pi templates.jpg",0)

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
w,h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.6

loc = np.where(res>=threshold)

for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img,pt,(pt[0]+w,pt[1]+h),(255,255,255),1)

cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Which particular line are you confused with?

Answer (score -1):

that's not for slicing if that's what you meant.
`[::-1]` is used to reverse lists

```
l = [1,2,3]
l = l[::-1]
print(l) # [3, 2, 1]
```